# Build failed with an exception in react-native-navigation package

Tags: react-native

I have added react-navigation library. I have installed Package and add dependencies too in app/build.gradle and android/setting.gradle. But after configuring about 66 i got error 
" Task :app:preDebugBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

  > Could not find com.android.support:appcompatv7:28.0.0.
  >   Required by:
  >     project :app"

Answer (score 0):

Add/replace the following code on `build.gragle` (project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 19
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
}
```

Update project dependencies in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourproject"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" 
    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')
}
```

And after that run:

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

Finally come back to your project and:

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: NO.. Do you want to see Error Screen?

Comment: Now my android studio is not building.

Comment: remove `@override` from this file: 
`C:\Users\07nis\AwesomeProject1\android\app\src\main\java\com\awesomeproject1\MainActivity.java` line 12 and try again. If your problem solved, please mark the answer and +1.